# Don't focus on text field after loading more comments in mobile

Tags: feature-request, comments, mobile-web, mobile-safari

On the desktop site, this isn't a problem, but on mobile it gets a little annoying

After tapping here to load more comments:

> [image]

The text field is shown, given focus, and then pushed out of view by the new comments.

What's left is a partially zoomed in view of the new comments, with a keyboard that can't be hidden until you scroll to find the text field.

> [image]

It's great that the field is shown, but can we not give it focus automatically?

Tested in Safari on iOS 7.1.1

Comment: I think 8 out of 10 times I have to minimize the keyboard. Yep, it's annoying.